# How did they get this table?

Tags: impulse-response, finite-impulse-response

I'm trying to work out how this table has been calculated in the attachments under part c. I thought it was $h[0]\star x[n]$ on the 4th row (first row with no label) and then $h[1]\star x[n-1]$ on the row below and then $h[2]\star x[x-2]$ but this doesn't get me the same values.

Would anyone be able to tell me?

Thanks 
[image]

Comment: Do _polynomial multiplication_ of \begin{align}h(z)&=1-2z+3z^2-4z^3+2z^4\\x(z)&=1-z+z^2\end{align} as $h(z)-zh(z)+z^2h(z)$ writing each of the polynomials $h(z)$, $-zh(z)$ and $z^2h(z)$ on three separate lines with powers of $z$ properly lined up in columns one above the other on each line. Then, write the sum of $h(z)$, $-zh(z)$ and $z^2h(z)$ on a fourth line, once again keeping all the different powers of $z$ properly lined up in columns. Now stare very hard _alternately_ at what you have written and the table you have shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that

> The output of an LTI system to an input is a weighted sum of shifted versions of the impulse response.

You can see that the input is $$x=(1)\delta[n]+(-1)\delta[n-1]+(1)\delta[n-2]$$
The response to $A\delta[n-n_0],\, \forall n_0$, is $Ah[n-n_0]$. By the principle of superposition, the output to a sum of shifted $\delta$ terms is a sum of shifted $h$ terms. Here:

$$y[n]=(1)h[n]+(-1)h[n-1]+(1)h[n-2]$$
where $h[n]$ is $$ \cdots \quad 0 \quad 1 \quad -2 \quad 3 \quad -4 \quad 2 \quad0\quad\cdots$$